# Is there have method to stop page loading in watir-webdriver

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Recently, in a test of my web application test by watir-webdriver, when a link click and a new page open. But the new is keep loading in a long time. And is there have a way to stop it and make browser.ready_state = 'complete' to continue the code follow it.

Comment: If you search, you will find 3 recent questions/answers regarding this topic in more detail, too.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see your code, but here's a stab at it:

```rb
@browser.my_button.when_present.click
```

The `when_present` will wait for asynchronous processes to load an element and then you can do an operation as soon as it loads.  No waits or sleeps needed.

I made a more detailed post about this [here](http://watirbender.blogspot.com/2012/04/perfidy-of-ajax-and-surprise-attacks.html), and you can also refer to the [RDoc](http://jarib.github.com/watir-webdriver/doc/Watir/Element.html#when_present-instance_method) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information? If it's a timeout, the timeout class works.

```
begin
  Timeout::timeout(10) do
end
```

Comment: To simply, when click a link and the other link of page is show,but the page is keep loading, so the code to click other link is not run, and as i know watir-webdriver will wait the page load complete and ready_state = 'complete' to continue other code, so i want to stop page loading and make the ready_state = 'complete' and not wait    so long time.