# how to click on browser "stop loading this page" using ruby watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

I want to click on browser "stop loading this page" icon, when timeout error occurs,what should i do for it? Some thing like this:

```
browser.stop   # this is wrong.
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched forever and the best I could come up with was:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3
```

This worked great for me with firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The below link may help you :

- [**Stop loading page watir-webdriver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831290/stop-loading-page-watir-webdriver)
- [**Is there have method to stop page loading in watir-webdriver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193140/is-there-have-method-to-stop-page-loading-in-watir-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this logic when you want to stop the loading,

```
@browser.send_keys :escape
```

It is not the best way of doing what you want but still the above approach worked out for me.

If you use Watir-Webdriver then you can try this for IE

```
@browser.execute_script "document.execCommand('Stop')"
```

Comment: seems not working for me, it still needs to wait for last action finished. And then show this error: Interrupt: net/protocol.rb:181:in `wait_readable'