# click_no_wait and then execute_script

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I'm using the page object gem with a page that contains a link.

When the link is clicked, the browser navigates to a new page, and the HTML renders as expected.

However, my script is always returning a `Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error`. After looking at the browser network activity, I noticed a pattern with a long running get that never completes.

If I run the script and then go to the console and issue the command
`$.connection.hub.stop()`, the script will not time out.

Is there a way to perform a `click_no_wait` or to click and then execute a script via the use of page_object_gem ?

Here is my page-object attempt, but it is resulting in a timeout still.

```
class MyThing

   include  PageObject
   include  PageObject::PageFactory

   link(:show_details, :id => 'detailLink')

   def click_show_details_no_wait
     begin
        show_details_element.click
     rescue Exception => e
       execute_script('$.connection.hub.stop();')
     end
   end 

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to suggest without your page. My first idea is to try to do

```
 show_details_element.fire_event('click')
```

instead of a usual click.

The second idea is take a look at

- [**Stop loading page watir-webdriver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831290/stop-loading-page-watir-webdriver)
- [**Is there have method to stop page loading in watir-webdriver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193140/is-there-have-method-to-stop-page-loading-in-watir-webdriver)
- [**how to click on browser “stop loading this page” using ruby watir?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592160/how-to-click-on-browser-stop-loading-this-page-using-ruby-watir)

Good luck.